# Cannot cast eclipse project to IJavaProject

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classcastexception, eclipse-jdt

I have the following code

```
    IJavaProject targetProject = null;
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    for (IProject project : root.getProjects()) {
        if (project.getName().equals(projName)) {
            try {
                if (project.hasNature("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")) {
                    targetProject = (IJavaProject) project;
                }
            } catch( ... ) {
             // etc ...
            }
```

What I am trying to do is essentially return a project that matches a particular name as an IJavaProject. As you can see, I check to ensure that the project in question has a java nature by calling:

```
if (project.hasNature("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")) {
```

Alas, I get a 'ClassCaseException' stating

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject
```

Any idea why? I would have thought that once an IProject has a java nature, it can be cast to a IJavaProject. I can't get access to the JDT Core API at the moment as the service is unavailable [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/jdom/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The code in your answer shouldn't work (typo?).  Here is how you can create an IJavaProject:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore
...
    if (project.hasNature(JavaCore.NATURE_ID)) {
        targetProject = JavaCore.create(project);
    }
```

`IProject` is a type in the Eclipse Resources API and IJavaProject is a type in the Eclipse Java Model.  They are not the same abstractions, but all IJavaProjects have an IProject.