# Eclipse - building workspace popup when saving file

Tags: java, eclipse

every time I save in eclipse I get the following popup message:

[image]

I have blitzed my whole .metadata directory and restarted but it still appears.  I have also deleted the resources dir at .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources as others have suggested from elsewhere.  How else can I solve this.  It's just a real annoyance!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642704/cannot-cast-eclipse-project-to-ijavaproject)? Dependening on what is discussed there: Could it be a problem of your code!?

Comment: No, code is fine.  I'm building with maven.  I fixed it anyways.  Always something simple!

Comment: @AlanSmith Please post your solution and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hi GGrec, I did below.  Jan's solution in the link below may also work, but my issue is solved by unchecking Build Automatically in the project tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is to uncheck the "Build Automatically" box under the Project tab in eclipse.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you but that stops eclipse from compiling your application and you won't recognize if you're having compiling problems within your projects. So don't think that this is a real solution.

Comment: No, still showing up the usual errors if I make a syntax mistake, unrecognised variable, etc.

Comment: Oh ok. So [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_build_project.htm) might be interesting for you.