# RCP plugin retrieving classpath of the runtime project

Tags: eclipse-rcp, classpath

I want to develop an editor for eclipse which works with java projects.

The plugin needs to know the resources in the classpath of the project of the open file. Since the question is quite ambigious i always find threads about the classpath of the bundle/plugin not the project edited with. Can someone tell me the right buzzword(runtime project) or share some code/links for that topic?

To be clear. This editor and its auto-completion/validation has to behave different whenever a classpath entry is added/removed same as the standard java-file editor.

Comment: A Java project is a [`IJavaProject`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html). That's what you're looking for, isn't it?

Comment: yes, with this hint i got bit further but unfortunately, when i ask the editor for the project it gives me  org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project, even if it is a JavaProject in eclipse

Comment: even if its description says 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature'

Comment: From the editor you should get an `IProject` with which you can do `if (project instanceof IJavaProject) { IJavaProject javaProject = (IJavaProject)project; /* your code goes here */ }`, can't you?

Comment: yes, i was expecting it to be an instance of IJP..., but its not, so i try to dig deeper here. Thanks for the help, it brought me little bit further, even if not to the end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642704/cannot-cast-eclipse-project-to-ijavaproject

Comment: I see. Do you think your question is a duplicate or do you want to answer your own question?

Comment: guess im answering it by myself in the context i am to have a full answer. thx again, your hint was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With helpful hint of @howgler i figured out how to get the classpath of the IJavaProject and scan it via google reflections. Hope that help somebody in the future.

```
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
    INSTANCE = this;
    super.init(site, input);
    FileEditorInput fei = (FileEditorInput) input;
    IFile file = fei.getFile();
    IProject project = file.getProject();
    try {
        if (project.hasNature(JavaCore.NATURE_ID)) {
            IJavaProject targetProject = JavaCore.create(project);
            final IClasspathEntry[] resolvedClasspath = targetProject.getResolvedClasspath(true);
            ArrayList<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
            for (IClasspathEntry classpathEntry : resolvedClasspath) {

                if (classpathEntry.getPath().toFile().isAbsolute()) {
                    urls.add(classpathEntry.getPath().toFile().toURI().toURL());
                } else {
                    urls.add(new File(project.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toFile(),classpathEntry.getPath().toString()).toURI().toURL());
                }
            }
            URLClassLoader urlCl = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]));

            Reflections reflections = new Reflections(urlCl,new TypeAnnotationsScanner(),new SubTypesScanner(true));
            Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(<???>.class);
            System.out.println(classes);
        }
    } catch (CoreException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```